# Preload dataset to the controller AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Hello Angular experts,

I have to preload a certain dataset (factory call to the database) to the controller. I don't use angular views so stateProvider or routeProvider cannot be used to resolve. Basically I need the dataset readily available before loading the controller.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I have a controller and a view. The view also has a widget. The widget has an attribute that expects a dataset. By the time the controller is done fetching data the view is already rendered so the widget input parameters are empty. So I need the widget dataset to be filled much before getting to the controller. By the way the app.run solution doesn't work as there is a promise involved.

Comment: This feels like an XY Question.  loading data is the job of a Controller, so it's not clear what you mean when you say you need the data before the Controller is loaded.  What **actual problem are you trying to solve here?**

Comment: Hi, i answer the question but remember OS (stackoverflow) it's not to just get answer it's a practice web, for that it's much better if you ask questions with sample you did before or at least you try to do it. thanks sam

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on your comment, what you are trying to do shouldn't require any changes to the Controller.

What you are **actually** trying to do is delay rendering of the widget component until you have data that the widget needs.  This is commonly handled by `ng-if` in your HTML.

For Example (pseudocode):

```
<div ng-if="myData">
    <Widget input="myData"></Widget>
</div>
```

Angular will not render this div until `myData` has a value, and all your Controller has to do is make sure `myData` is added to `$scope`.

Comment: You are right Claies. Sorry for the confusion. All good. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't say as **before loading controller**, i correct it with **before binding controller**

`angularjs` has `app.run` and i think you know it, it work just when application run (first time) and every time you refresh it.

---

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.run(function($http, $rootScope) {
   $http.get("url").then(function(response){
      console.log(response.data)
      $rootScope.data = response.data; // as global scope
   })
})

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.$watch('data', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      if(newValue){
         console.log(newValue) // you will get `rootscope.data` when it's ready
      }
   })
})
```

---

> You can add factory to the app run too.

**please fill free to ask question**.

Comment: Thank you for the responses so far. As Claies pointed out let me elaborate on the issue . I have a controller and a view. The view also has a widget. The widget has an attribute that expects a dataset. By the time the controller is done fetching data the view is already rendered so the widget input parameters are empty. So I need the widget dataset to be filled much before getting to the controller. By the way the app.run solution doesn't work as there is a promise involved.  Any views on this issue is much appreciated. Thanks